# Why is a 'use' statement executed first in a BEGIN block?

Tags: perl, compile-time

When I execute the following code, I get  `Can't locate SomePackage.pm in @INC ...`.

```
BEGIN {
    die;
    use SomePackage;
}
```

Why is `use` executed before `die`?

Comment: Not quite sure but use is evaluated at compile time and die at run time.

Comment: @M42 Well, `BEGIN` blocks are also evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`use SomePackage` is exactly equivalent to

```
BEGIN { require SomePackage; SomePackage->import }
```

A `BEGIN` code block is executed as soon as possible, that is, the moment it is *completely defined*. The second `BEGIN` (which is implied by `use`) is completely defined first, and is thus executed first.

Answer (score 1):

From http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html

> Because use takes effect at compile
>   time, it doesn't respect the ordinary
>   flow control of the code being
>   compiled.